# No puedo instalar el paquete now en linux

Tags: nodejs, linux, express

Estoy en un curso de nodejs y cuando el docente instalo el npm i -g now me salio todo esto, en mac pude instalarlo al igual que en win 10, pero estoy tratando de hacer todo en linux(zorin os 15.3)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal como te dice en el error, tu usuario parece no tener permiso de escritura en /usr/local/lib

Comment: Solo una pregunta, le preguntastes a tu docente antes que nosotros?

Comment: ya le di permisos y aun así no puedo instalar

Comment: no es clases en vivo, solo es un curso de udemy, pregunte y me dijo lo mismo, dar permisos a mi usuario, en win 10 y mac no tuve problemas

Comment: Que hay en el log que se indica en tu imagen?

Comment: usa `sudo` y debería funcionar.